# Knockout.js databinding with jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a button which I want to bind to a method in the VM using knockout.  I am using the following code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cmdCreateConnection" 
        data-bind="click: function(data, event) {
                               createConnection($('#connectuser').val(), 
                                                'param2', data, event)
                          }">Create connection
</button>
```

One of the parameters to the method are values entered into a textbox, hence the selector `$('#connectuser').val()`.

However this does not work, any ideas?

Comment: You should post the whole problem (html + javascript including VM)

Comment: There is also a missing ';' in the data-bind attribute, before the '}'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding an id to your button declaration and by accessing the textbox value through JQuery, you're actually violating the main concept behind KnockoutJS and the two-way data binding concept. Instead, your button declaration should be something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: doSomething">Create connection</button>
```

And your textbox should be declared like:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: doSomethingParameter" />
```

In your ViewModel file, you must declare an observable "doSomethingParameter" and access its value through the function "doSomething":

```
self.doSomethingParameter = ko.observable();

self.doSomething= function () {

    alert(self.doSomethingParameter());

};
```